# How to extract stan code from .stan file in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, stan

I want to display the stan code in Rmarkdon not using {stan} chunk.
Now I'm searching the way of extracting the stan code from stan file(.stan) but, I can only find the way extracting stan code from stanfit object.

Is there any function in Rstan package or other packages ?
If there are some solution, please teach me how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused. The Stan file itself is the Stan code. Hence, displaying the Stan code in Rmarkdown is very straightforward, if you do not wish to use the Stan chunk:

```
writeLines(readLines("filename.stan"))
```

Let me know if this was not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in some situations you may forget what the model syntax was after you fit the model you can use:

```
fit@stanmodel
```